# Javascript/jQuery - Add class from option list (dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onchange

[image]
So I have a list of filters when on clicked on it it should add a class to the `img`, so when clicked on the filter brannan it should add `class='brannan'` to the img, the **option and value** are identical to the class one. How can I know `addClass();` to the image, for example, if I select the filter *brannan* it should add the class brannan to the img.

```
<div class="form__field">
        <img id="preview" src="#" alt="Image preview" />
</div>

 <div class="form__field">    
        <select name="filter">
            <option value="_1977">1977</option>
            <option value="aden">aden</option>
            <option value="brannan">brannan</option>
            <option value="brooklyn">brooklyn</option>
            <option value="clarendon">clarendon</option>
        </select>
```

I'm assuming the code will follow something like `onchange` on the select -> get value of it -> `addClass();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about needing an `onChange` function then you can just set the class to that of the value:

```js
var selectElem = document.querySelector('.form__field select');

selectElem.onchange = function() {
  document.querySelector('#preview').className = this.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="form__field">
        <img id="preview" src="#" alt="Image preview" />
</div>

<div class="form__field">    
        <select name="filter">
            <option value="_1977">1977</option>
            <option value="aden">aden</option>
            <option value="brannan">brannan</option>
            <option value="brooklyn">brooklyn</option>
            <option value="clarendon">clarendon</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

add class using [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) function on [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event. Also remove the class using [`removeClass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

```js
$("select[name='[filter]'").on('change',function(){
  var prevClass = $('img').attr('class');
  $('img').removeClass(prevClass);
  $('img').addClass($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<div class="form__field">
        <img id="preview" src="#" alt="Image preview" />
</div>

 <div class="form__field">    
        <select name="filter">
            <option value="_1977">1977</option>
            <option value="aden">aden</option>
            <option value="brannan">brannan</option>
            <option value="brooklyn">brooklyn</option>
            <option value="clarendon">clarendon</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Just FYI you can use `removeClass()` with no arguments to remove all classes. Therefore you can simplify this to just `$('img').removeClass().addClass($(this).val());`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan exactly, we also can do that. :) Thank you for your sweet suggestion friend.

Answer (score 1):

Add an onchange  listener on `select` and add the selected value as class to the div where you want it

```js
$("select").change(function(){
     console.log("Adding class ",$(this).val())
    $("#preview").removeClass();
    $("#preview").addClass($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form__field">
        <img id="preview" src="#" alt="Image preview" />
</div>
<select name="filter">
            <option value="_1977">1977</option>
            <option value="aden">aden</option>
            <option value="brannan">brannan</option>
            <option value="brooklyn">brooklyn</option>
            <option value="clarendon">clarendon</option>
        </select>
```

Note: You don't want to keep the previously added class in `img` so `$("#preview").removeClass();` is to remove all previously added classes and add the current important class

Answer (score 1):

Try the following with jQuery's `change`, `addClass()` and `removeClass()`:

```js
var classToRemove = '';
$('[name=filter]').change(function(){
  $('#preview').removeClass(classToRemove);
  $('#preview').addClass($(this).val());
  classToRemove = $(this).val();
  
  //For demonstration
  console.log($('#preview').attr('class'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form__field">
  <img id="preview" src="#" alt="Image preview" />
</div>

<div class="form__field">    
<select name="filter">
  <option value="_1977">1977</option>
  <option value="aden">aden</option>
  <option value="brannan">brannan</option>
  <option value="brooklyn">brooklyn</option>
  <option value="clarendon">clarendon</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the `input` event instead of the `change` event for more browser compatibility.

```js
$( '[name=filter]' ).on( 'input propertychange', function() {
 $( '#preview' ).removeClass().addClass( ($( this ).val() ) );
 console.log( 'The image has a class named: ' + $( '#preview' ).attr( 'class' ) )
});
```

```css
#preview {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid
}
.default {
  border-color: black
}
.blue {
  border-color: blue
}
.yellow {
  border-color: yellow
}
.red {
  border-color: red
}
.green {
  border-color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form__field">
 <img id="preview" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ef95d6eafc29a0cd76af27acc45da6dd?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image preview" class="default" />
</div>

<div class="form__field">    
 <select name="filter">
  <option value="default">Default</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
 </select>
</div>
```